# Wordpress post table

Tags: html, css, wordpress, content-management-system

some of my blog posts contain tables. I know I can just insert html directly into the blog and it applies the tags correctly to form a table, however my friend also wants to post such tables and he is scared of the html. Is there a way to insert tables into blogs easily without using html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this plugin to add buttons to the rich text editor. It includes tabling functions. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/